# Go into sudo user, run couple of commands, go back to normal user in Python script

Tags: python, shell

The problem I've run into is that I want to temporarily get into the sudo user, run a couple of commands, and then go back to a normal user and run the commands in that mode.

You can find the script I'm gonna use it in here: https://github.com/Greduan/dotfiles/blob/master/scripts/symlinks.py

Basically, when I'm installing the scripts under the `/bin` folder of my dotfiles I need sudo access in order to make a symlink to that folder. You can find this part of the script under the last for statement in the code.

However, since I do depend on some commands that use the current user as a guideline to do stuff, I can't just run the entire script as `sudo`. Last time I tried I got a lot of errors about a folder not existing.

Thanks for all the help you can provide.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind installing an external dependency, the [`sh` module](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/) makes this pretty simple:

```
import sh

sh.cp('foo.txt', 'bar.txt')

with sh.sudo:
    sh.cp('foo2.txt', 'bar2.txt')
```

Comment: Would this allow me to do `sh.ln('s', original_file, target file)` or something like that?

Comment: @Eduan: Sure. You'd do `sh.ln('-s', original_file, target_file)` or `sh.ln(symbolic=True, original_file, target_file)`.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I tried @Blender's solution, but it didn't work or I wasn't able to figure it out.

So Instead I did the following:

```
subprocess.Popen('sudo rm ' + final_dest, shell=True)
```

and:

```
subprocess.Popen('sudo ln -s ' + final_src + ' ' + final_dest, shell=True)
```

This works correctly as I expected it and it has no extra dependencies. Thanks for your answer @Blender but it didn't work for me. ;|

Comment: `os.popen` has been [deprecated for years](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen). Don't use it.

Comment: @Cairnarvon What should I use instead then? Out of all the things I've tried it's the only thing that I can understand and that works...

Comment: If you'll *read the documentation I linked*, it will tell you to use the `subprocess` module instead, and offers a straightforward guide to convert old code.

Comment: @Cairnarvon sorry about that. Missed the link the first time. I fixed my answer now, is it good now? It works, I think, it doesn't ask me for the password...